# Can't deserialize JSON to enum

Tags: c#, json, enums, json.net, deserialization

When I try to deserialize the JSON I always get an error.
The `CoubType` is included in the `CoubBig` class. An example for the JSON: http://coub.com/api/v2/coubs/4951721

### Code

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum CoubType
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "Coub::Simple")]
    Simple = 1,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Coub::Temp")]
    Temp = 2,
    EnumMember(Value = "Coub::Recoub")]
    Recoub = 3
}
```

---

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CoubBig>(await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

---

```
public partial class CoubBig
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public CoubType Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("permalink")]
    public string Permalink { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("visibility_type")]
    public VisibilityType VisibilityType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("original_visibility_type")]
    public VisibilityType OriginalVisibilityType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("channel_id")]
    public int ChannelId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("created_at")]
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("updated_at")]
    public DateTimeOffset UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("is_done")]
    public bool IsDone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("views_count")]
    public int ViewsCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cotd")]
    public bool Cotd { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cotd_at")]
    public object CotdAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("original_sound")]
    public bool OriginalSound { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("has_sound")]
    public bool HasSound { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("recoub_to")]
    public int RecoubTo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("file_versions")]
    public FileVersions FileVersions { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("audio_versions")]
    public AudioVersions AudioVersions { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("image_versions")]
    public ThumbnailImageVersions ImageVersions { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("first_frame_versions")]
    public FirstFrameVersions FirstFrameVersions { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dimensions")]
    public Dimensions Dimensions { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("age_restricted")]
    public bool AgeRestricted { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("allow_reuse")]
    public bool AllowReuse { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("banned")]
    public bool Banned { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("external_download")]
    public ExternalDownload ExternalDownload { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("channel")]
    public ChannelSmall Channel { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("percent_done")]
    public long PercentDone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tags")]
    public Tag[] Tags { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("recoubs_count")]
    public long RecoubsCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("likes_count")]
    public long LikesCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("raw_video_id")]
    public long RawVideoId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("media_blocks")]
    public MediaBlocks MediaBlocks { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("raw_video_thumbnail_url")]
    public Uri RawVideoThumbnailUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("raw_video_title")]
    public string RawVideoTitle { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty("video_block_banned")]
    public bool VideoBlockBanned { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("duration")]
    public float Duration { get; set; }
}
```

Exception

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value
>   "Coub::Simple" to type 'Coub.Net.Objects.CoubType'. Path 'type', line
>   1, position 162.'
>   **Inner Exception**
>  ArgumentException: Requested value 'Coub::Simple' was not found.

Why it isn't working?

Comment: Can you post your data model (`CoubBig`) ?

Comment: @Neil Here you are.

Comment: Can't reproduce.  I tried deserializing the JSON at http://coub.com/api/v2/coubs/4951721 using `CoubBig` after commenting out properties with undefined types, and `Type` was deserialized successfully.  I did find two properties that needed to be made nullable: `public bool? Cotd { get; set; }` and `public int? RecoubTo { get; set; }`.  What version of Json.NET are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem source.
When I tried to use the `EnumMember` attribute I could not *(since`System.Runtime.Serialization` was not added to the project)* so I searched for its source code and inserted it into the project. When I got a better look, I noticed that `System.Runtime.Serialization` was not added to the project. I deleted the attribute I inserted and added `System.Runtime.Serialization` to the project. Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can get help from the code below to convert  class to json

```
public enum Role
{
    Admin,
    Guest
}
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Role Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Conversion json by

```
public User ConvertJson(string json)
{
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
    return obj;
}
```

Two patterns json

```
{  'Name': 'Your Name', 'Active': true, 'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z','Roles': 'Admin'}


{  'Name': 'Your Name', 'Active': true, 'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z','Roles': 1 }
```

Comment: It's not that simple. For example, in JSON I get this: `Coub::Simple` which does not match either `Simple` or `1`. And it seems that the attributes do not change it either.